# Encoding with random 1bit gain/loss

Tags: algorithm, encoding, compression

I'd like to ask a question that I tried to answer myself but couldn't come up with any solution.

I'd like to know of any algorithm (or if it's possible at least to prove whether one does or doesn't exist), with these properties

```
              +-----------+
status_in --> | ALGORITHM | --> status_out
              +-----------+
```

1. "status_out" is 1 bit larger or 1 bit smaller than the original "status_in" with a random 50% chance
2. from "status_out" I can always go back to "status_in"

Sorry in advance if the question is not well formed and maybe lacks some important details, but those are basically the only two properties that I'm interested in and I'm not able to rephrase the question more precisely.

Thank you in advance for any help, and please let me know if there are any more details that I could give to make my question more clear.

Comment: Are all cominations of `status_in` possible? In other words, if `status_in` contains `k` bits, are there `2^k` possible values for it? (If yes, it is easy to prove such algorithm cannot exist. Otherwise, a simple example would be removing a sign bit from an integer that has to be positive)

Comment: What do you mean by "I can always go back to "status_in"" ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Basically a "one-to-one mapping", or that it's "reversible"? This might be the right term. After I've applied the algorithm to status_in and I'm in a new state status_out, I can go back. For example `y=x+1` is "reversible", whereas `y=x^2` is not.

Comment: @J.Cassini: a one-to-one mapping is obviously impossible when you drop a bit !

Comment: @J.Cassini: after seeing your comments I conclude that you want to encode parts of the values on k-1 bits and other values on k+1. If the length of the encoding is known, then this is no problem as the given of the length provides an extra bit of information. So all short codes just have to be padded with a 0, and the long ones to be truncated by one bit (which can be assigned a random value).

Comment: @YvesDaoust "If the length of the encoding is known", yes indeed this is known. I would know the exact values of status_in and status_out, hence by extension I'd aldo know their size/length. However I'm having some trouble understanding how to put your suggestion into practice. Could you please give an example?

Comment: 00, 01, 10, 11 are 000, 001, 010, 011, and 0100, 1101, 0110, 1111, are 100, 101, 110, 111.

Comment: Thank you @YvesDaoust, however I'm not sure that this example really works. When you do for example `01 -> 001` you've added 1 bit. On the other hand when you encode the 4 bits into 3, either you're missing out half of the combinations or the leading bit can be either 0 or 1, in which case you haven't "removed 1 bit of information" even though the length changed from 4 to 3, because you still need to save that bit somewhere else in order to recover the original status_in.

Comment: @J.Cassini: you read it in reverse. k=3.

Comment: Ah I see, basically what you say is if the input is `0xy -> xy` else `1xy -> z1xy`. The issue with this approach is that if `k=5`, then all input starting with `0` will map to 4 bits, so I can't really distinguish if the original input was `k=3`  or `k=5`  :-(

Comment: Random chance? So the algorithm is not deterministic?

Answer (score 1):

1. If all bits of `status_in` are used (if there are `k` bits in
   `status_in`, then it can have `2^k` different values, each different
   from each other):

   In this case, it is easy to show that there is no such algorithm. Firt note that `status_out` has `k-1` bits, and thus maximum number of values possible for `status_out` is `2^(k-1)`. Since `2^k > 2^(k-1)`, that means there is some `x,y` (of `status_in`) such that `f(x) = f(y)`. However, given `f(x)`, you cannot tell which is the original: `x` or `y`.
2. If the possible values of `status_in` is not including all possibilities, then yes. Take for example a 32 bits signed integer (`int` in most languages), that due to some other restrictions, have to be possible. You can remove the sign bit (which is always 0), and get a 31 bits number. Since you know the source is always possible, adding the `0` back is easy.

Comment: 'If the possible values of status_in is not including all possibilities, then yes'. So save one bit you need that **at least half** of the values are unused.

Comment: Yes I'm interested in any `2^k` status_in. However 1) I'm **not** trying to compress all `2^k` into `2^(k-1)`, which your answer seems to suggest and which I agree is obviously impossible. I'm just interested to know if, for any status_in, half of the status_in `2^k` inputs can be encoded with `2^(k-1)` bits, and the other half can be encoded with `2^(k+1)` bits instead,   2) your example is about *always removing 1 bit*, which is **not** what I'm interested in. Also, did you mean "s/possible/positive"?

Answer (score 0):

Going from left to right you are erasing a bit of information half the time, so by [Landauer's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle) you the left to right process causes an entropy increase in the system's environment.

For the process to be reversible, recovering 'status_in' from 'status_out', you need to have a means of pulling entropy from the environment, i.e. a perpetual motion machine.

Comment: What? I think this is a bit tangential and not relevant to the question. "Reversible" would just mean a one-to-one mapping, such as `y = x + 1`. That's all. Also, "going from left to right" wouldn't be strictly about "erasing a bit of information", but "erasing or adding a bit of information" instead.

Answer (score 0):

I will ignore the use of the word "random" in your question, and assume that you are asking about a deterministic algorithm. Therefore when you say 50%, I will take that to mean *exactly* half of the possible inputs are one bit shorter, and *exactly* half are one-bit longer. I am also assuming that you know by some means the length in bits of the input and output messages, so that codes can share common prefixes. I.e. the output string of bits does not have to be self-terminating. Also I will assume that you do not need to code a zero-bit-length input. There is at least one bit of input. However a zero-bit output is allowed.

The answer is, yes, if `status_in` is a single fixed numbers of bits. The answer is no if `status_in` can be any number of bits.

So if `status_in` is *k* bits, then half of them can be encoded in *k-1* bits, using all of the possible *k-1* bit strings. The other half can be encoded in one-fourth of the available *k+1* bit strings. This is reversible.

However if `status_in` can be any number of bits, we run into a conflict between the mappings of *k* and *k+2* bits. To encode *k* bits, we use one-fourth of the *k+1* bit values. However to encode *k+2* bits, we use *all* of the *k+1* bit values. So there are not enough *k+1* bit values. This is first seen when coding 1 bit and 3 bits. One of the 1-bit values codes to zero bits, and the other codes to 2 bits. However when coding 3 bits, four of the 3-bit values codes to *all* of the possible 2-bit values, but we already used one for one of the 1-bit values. So it can't be done.